# inet_ntoa() in Winsock2 is deprecated?

Tags: c++, winsock, winsock2

I was experimenting with Winsock2 at the moment, and got a warning that `inet_ntoa()` is deprecated and that I should use `inet_pton()`. I tried it, but it was little endian, so the whole string that was saved in the buffer was "wrong". I'm guessing `inet_ntoa()` is big endian?

And I could only use `inet_pton()` with `#include <ws2tcpip.h>`, so for me it just gets more confusing from here on. Why should I use something else outside the `<winsock2.h>` library?

Currently, I'm avoiding this by using `#pragma warning(disable : 4996)`, which I don't like, because I just don't want to ignore all warnings.

This whole Winsock topic is like a maze for me, sorry if I'm missing some information, hope that's enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inet_pton()` is NOT the successor for `inet_ntoa()`, but for `inet_addr()` instead.  You want [`inet_ntop()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-inet_ntop) instead.

`inet_ntoa()`/`inet_ntop()` convert an IP address from binary form to string form.  `inet_addr()`/`inet_pton()` do the opposite conversion.

However, there are actually several functions that you can use instead of `inet_ntoa()`, including [`getnameinfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getnameinfo), [`WSAAddressToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaaddresstostringa), [`RtlIpv4AddressToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ip2string/nf-ip2string-rtlipv4addresstostringa)/[`RtlIpv6AddressToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ip2string/nf-ip2string-rtlipv6addresstostringa), etc.

That being said, yes `inet_ntoa()` is indeed deprecated, because it only support IPv4 addresses.  Functions like `inet_ntop()`, `getnameinfo()`, etc support both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, which makes writing IP version-agnostic code a bit easier.

If you are having trouble with `inet_ntop()` then you are using it wrong, but you did not show your code.  IPv4 addresses are always expressed in binary form in "network byte order" (big endian), even on little endian systems, like Windows.

As for `<ws2tcpip.h>`, that is part of the Winsock2 library.  Nothing requires an API to only have 1 header file (indeed, the Win32 API as a whole consists of *thousands* of header files, beginning with but not limited to `<windows.h>`).

The correct way to deal with the deprecation warning is to update your code to use a modern API that is not deprecated, like it wants you to.  Otherwise, if that is not an option for you at this time, then at the very least you can use `#pragma warning(suppress : 4996)` on just the affected code, rather than use `#pragma warning(disable : 4996)` globally.  Or, you can define `_WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS` in your project setup, or you can `#define` it in your code before `#include`'ing any Winsock2 headers.

Comment: Thanks alot for explaining ! this is what i needed, i searched trough google found some tutorials, looked deeper into the functions themselves, but microsoft docs werent helpfull at all. SO again, thanks alot u saved me another day of searching trough google haha.

Comment: Last Update, for some reason i tought https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2def/ns-ws2def-sockaddr_in, was SOCKADDR_IN, but that was inside SOCKADDR_IN, it works like intended, i just feeded the function wrong information. Closed...

Comment: @cpnuub I think you are referring to [`IN_ADDR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/inaddr/ns-inaddr-in_addr) instead, right?

Comment: exactly, thats why i posted the link, there u can see the only IN_ADDR variable is "sin_addr"

Answer (score 0):

`inet_ntoa()` has several limitations that limit its usefulness in the modern world.

For one thing, it only works for IPv4 addresses -- if you need to convert an IPv6 address into human-readable text, you're out of luck as far as `inet_ntoa()` is concerned.

Another problem is that `inet_ntoa()` returns a `char *` that points to a static buffer, which is problematic -- if you don't immediately copy out the string into somewhere else, the static buffer's contents might be overwritten by another sockets-API call before you read it, which could be a difficult runtime bug to track down and fix.  (There might also be race-conditions possible when multiple threads are calling `inet_ntoa()` around the same time, although the wording of Microsoft's [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-inet_ntoa) makes me suspect that Microsoft may be returning a pointer to a thread-local buffer to avoid that particular can of worms)

Best practice would therefore be to avoid calling `inet_ntoa()` if possible, and call its modern replacement [inet_ntop()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-inet_ntop) instead.  (`inet_ntop()` is a bit harder to use, but it avoids the problems listed above)

Comment: Yes, `inet_ntoa()` uses a thread-local buffer, so it is safe to call concurrently in multiple threads. But you are right, one of the more modern functions that take a user-supplied buffer should be used instead.